# Defining color in minipage makes it too big for the current page

Tags: color, minipage

If I uncomment the first line of the `minipage`, the `minipage` is then too big to fit on the page.  What's happening here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}
      [t][\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax]
         {\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
%    \color{blue}

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{minipage}}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you set `\color{blue}` before the `minipage`, just at the start of `\fbox`? The problem is `\color{blue}` before starting a paragraph, which creates every kind of evil.

Comment: Replacing `\color{blue}` with `\leavevmode` has the same effect.

Comment: @egreg, great! I'd imagined that. But why does it start a paragraph? What is the advantage on it?

Comment: @jfbu Yes, but creates a one line paragraph, if the blank line is not removed.

Comment: @egreg Is there a place where I can learn what these various *evils* are?  Also, what other commands before a paragraph will also create *every kind of evil?*

Comment: @egreg sorry I meant `has the same effect as the original code` not `has the same effect as your suggestion` !! Indeed I left the blank line.

Comment: @egreg and I was going to add `use \leavevmode\color{blue}\lipsum etc...` but David's answer came in-between...

Comment: @jfbu sorry only saw this comment thread apart from egregs initial comment after I posted:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... one has to be quick here, and when I saw `one new answer` I knew without any need to click that the creator of the thing was probably settling up the matter! ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a feature (documented even) of the color package that it will mess up alignment in this instance. `grfguide.tex` distributed with LaTeX says

> There is a different type of problem that will occur for all drivers.
>   Due to certain technical difficulties\footnote{At least two causes: 1)
>   The presence of a `\special` *whatsit* prevents
>   `\addvspace` 'seeing' space on the current vertical
>   list, so causing it to incorrectly add extra vertical space. 2) A
>   *whatsit* as the first item in a `\vtop` moves the
>   reference point of the box.}

and `\begin{minipage}[t]` is a `\vtop`.

So you can use `\leavevmode\color{blue}` If you can place the color immediately before the text of the box (ie no blank line, or `\begin{enumerate}` etc) or as egreg suggested in comments move the color out of the vertical box and place it at the start of the `\fbox`.

Comment: What exactly is a *whatsit*?

Comment: @A.Ellett: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43174/2975

Comment: That's probably a new question. TEX lists can contain various types of things horizontal and vertical boxes, glue, kerns, penalties, rules, characters, marks, inserts, discretionaries and _whatsits_ which are a hypothetical extension point for implementers to add new node types but two "example" whatsits are defined write nodes and \special (and some pdftex built-in special-like commands like \pdfliteral) so color is marked by soomething like `\special{postscript command for blue}` but that is a node in the vertical list _before_  text so forms the reference point of minipage[t]