# make biblatex cite all papers despite includeonly

Tags: biblatex

I use `\includeonly` to do the page layout for single chapters. I worked an our one a lengthy chapter only to find out that it does not work with the whole document. After some search I found the reason. A single letter caused a cascade of different page layouts. When I did the layout with only one chapter included there was just one paper by Müller from 2004 in this chapter and the following was the result:

[image]

In the full book, I had four papers and I got a reference to Müller (2004d) instead of Müller (2004). This single letter caused the paragraph to take an extra line, which caused two lines floating to the next page, which ruined everything I did so far.

[image]

So, question: Can I make biblatex to include everthing it finds cited in aux files?

**Edit 1:**

I adapted https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418639/18561 to biblatex, but it does not work. It only cites one reference. bibtex works out of the box without any additional mechanisms.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\def\mincludeonly#1{\foreach \file in {#1} {\xdef\temp{#1}\global\expandafter\let\csname fileincluded\file\endcsname\temp}}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\def\savecitations#1{\savebox\mybox{\vbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{\textwidth}\include{#1}\end{minipage}}}}
\def\minclude#1{\ifcsname fileincluded#1\endcsname\include{#1}\else\savecitations{#1}%More needed commands
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
\fi}

\mincludeonly{chap1}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{item1,
  title = {Title Item 1},
  year  = {1998},
  author = {Author},
}
@article{item2,
  title = {Title Item 1},
  year  = {1998},
  author = {Author},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{test 1}
  This is a citation:\cite{item1}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{test 2}
  This is a citation:\cite{item2}

  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\minclude{chap1}
%\minclude{chap2}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:**

MWE based on the code above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\includeonly{chap1}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{item1,
  title = {Title Item 1},
  year  = {1998},
  author = {Author},
}
@article{item2,
  title = {Title Item 1},
  year  = {1998},
  author = {Author},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{test 1}
  This is a citation:\cite{item1}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{test 2}
  This is a citation:\cite{item2}

  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\include{chap1}
%\include{chap2}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about adding a `\nocite{*}` somewhere on the code? Seems simple solution too me (It could be included in the `\includeonly` command if you want)

Comment: I have almost 6000 items in the bibliography. I would not want to have all in there. But in principle this workaround could be made to work. I have scripts that bild me a subbibliography with all I cite. I could use this bibliography and then do \nocite{*}. However, this would involve some extra runs through the whole document and given how powerful biblatex is there is probably a better way.

Comment: I know this is a general question and it does not need an MWE to be understood. But you would certainly make my life easier if you could provide a short, self-contained example (using `filecontents` for the `\include`d chapters) that shows the behaviour. I wanted to look at this just now, but the fact that I have to set up all this stuff means I'll probably wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @StefanMüller, the problem was that second `\minclude` was commented out. Fixed that and mede the code easy to test usibg a variable `\testonbiblatex` (1 for biblatex other integer for bibtex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do now: I copy my main file that includes the chapters to a file (check-gt.tex) and change the bibliography that is loaded (check-gt.bib). Instead of using my bibliography that contains 6000 items I use the bib that cites all items in the book (just 1471). I include a `\nocite{*}` in this file so that all items that are cited in the full book (grammatical-theory.tex) are also cited in the file that does not include all chapters (check-gt.tex). The following line produces the list of references that I include

```
 biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve grammatical-theory.bcf -O check-gt.bib
```

This has to be done once and I do not have to compile all the files that are not included. The book is over 800 pages long and I guess this solution is the most efficient one.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` always writes to the main `.aux` file, so the `.aux` files for the chapters do not contain enough information. But even if that were changed, the issue is still `biblatex` does not only manage its citations with the `.aux` file, it also writes them to the `.bcf`.

`biblatex` only writes to the `.bcf` if the citation is actually processed by TeX. If the citation lives in a file not included in the current run, the citations are not processed.

The following is a copy of the original `\include` and `\includeonly` (see [`ltfiles.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltfiles.dtx) or [`source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf)) that also secretly `\input`s the chapter in a box that is never printed to let LaTeX process it for citations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \cite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \cite{worman,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@blx@partsw \@blx@partswfalse

\def\blxincludeonly#1{%
  \@blx@partswtrue
  \edef\@blx@partlist{\zap@space#1 \@empty}}
\@onlypreamble\blxincludeonly

\def\blxinclude#1{\relax
  \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
    \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
  \else \@blx@include#1 \fi}

\def\@blx@include#1 {%
  \clearpage
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}%
  \fi
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@blx@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@blx@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux #1.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \@input@{#1.tex}%
    \clearpage
    \@writeckpt{#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  \else
    \setbox0=\vbox{\begingroup\@input@{#1.tex}\endgroup}%
    \deadcycles\z@
    \@nameuse{cp@#1}%
  \fi
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux}
\makeatletter

\blxincludeonly{chap2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blxinclude{chap1}
\blxinclude{chap2}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does not seem to work for my wild code.! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.230 \centering
                
?

Comment: @StefanMüller Yes, since we have to process the files that were not `\includeonly`'d we need to hide the output. We do that in a `\vbox`. While that works well for simple text, it can go wrong with floats and other things. ... Not sure if there is a good way. I only found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97347/35864 and that leaves an unwanted empty page ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with my versions of`\include` and `\includeonly` commands:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%CHANGE TO 1 FOR BIBLATEX(BIBER)
\xdef\testonbiblatex{0}

%THE PART OF CODE NEEDED
\xdef\inclonl{0}
\def\mincludeonly#1{\xdef\inclonl{1}\foreach \file in {#1} {\xdef\temp{#1}\global\expandafter\let\csname fileincluded\file\endcsname\temp}}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\def\savecitations#1{\savebox\mybox{\vbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[inner sep=0]{\textwidth}\include{#1}\end{minipage}}}}
\def\minclude#1{\ifnum\inclonl=1\ifcsname fileincluded#1\endcsname\include{#1}\else\savecitations{#1}%More needed commands
  %This indented part fix the isue of @moewe's commant about pages numbers  
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pagestobeadded{int(round((\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox)/\textheight))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\morepagestobeadded{round((\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox)/\textheight)-(\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox)/\textheight))}%
  \ifdim\morepagestobeadded pt>0pt %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\finalpagestobeadded{int(\pagestobeadded)}%
  \else%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\finalpagestobeadded{int(\pagestobeadded+1)}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{page}{\finalpagestobeadded}%
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
\fi\else\include{#1}\fi}

%ADDED FOR EASY TEST
\ifnum\testonbiblatex=1
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\fi

\mincludeonly{chap1}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
  \@article{item1,
    title = {Title Item 1},
    year  = {1998},
    author = {Author}}
    \@article{item2,
    title = {Title Item 2},
    year  = {1998},
    author = {Author}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{test 1}
  This is a citation:\cite{item1}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{test 2}
  This is a citation:\cite{item2}

  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\minclude{chap1}
\minclude{chap2}%My problem on your question Edit 1 was a % here

%ADDED just to make easy check of chapter numbers and possible side effects
\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1-2]

%ADDED FOR EASY TEST
\ifnum\testonbiblatex=1
\printbibliography
\else
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\fi


\end{document}
```

Of course it will be much slower because it will read all the chapters included or not... But the idea can be used in other ways too.

(I haven't use or check enough how the original  \includeonly command is supposed to work and I am not sure what would be the way to not use the other chapters... but this can be fixed in your needs I suppose)

Edit: all the parts with comment %ADDED FOR EASY TEST , are needed only to test between biblatex(biber) [variable `\testonbiblatex` value =1] and bibtex. The only needed change I made was to remove the "%" between second `\minclude` command. Also changed second article title but not really needed to work.

Output (bibtex):

[image]

Output (biblatex):

[image]

Comment: Please l;et me know the changes that you would like to have (like reducing the chapter by one for nun included or similar -this added- )

Comment: I suppose my answer works both on bibtex and  biblatex

Comment: First photo added before change "Title item 1" to "Title item 2"...

Comment: Mhhh it may just be me, but the logic for `\mincludeonly` doesn't quite seem to do what I expect. If there is no `\mincludeonly` I only get `chapter1`. And if I have `\mincludeonly{chap1}` I get to see both chapters ...

Comment: Thanks @moewe, the logic is exactly what you used in your code (as far as I can understand the phrase "a copy of the original \include and \includeonly that also secretly \inputs the chapter in a box that is never printed to let LaTeX process it for citations.")... I can not really understand your code... but this is the logic of my code. My mistake was that didn't thought of the case of  non command `\includeonly`  is present and solved it with an addition of a variable. Thanks

Comment: Good! That works now. But as far as I can see your solution does not preserve page numbers. If all chapters are printed the bibliography is on page 9, but if we do `\mincludeonly` the bibliography goes to page 4. With standard `\include`/`\includeonly` the bibliography would stay on page 9.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't knew that this is the way of `\includeonly` possibly there are more differences too. This is what I mentioned in my parenthesis under answers. I would call the old `\includeonly{}`  `\printonly{}` :P in this case. Anyway this is easy to be fixed...

Comment: Found that still need some improvements

Comment: Anyway the current problem is when you try to include in doublesided... If someone find it useful  just message me to fix it...

Comment: Chapter numbers are not preserved either. If I includeonly chap1 the chapter in the main body should be chapter 3 but it is chapter 2. You seem to throw away too much.

Comment: @StefanMüller the command `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%` added to let chapters keep a real order but this is not how it supposed to work for you (It is for me, but this is something else)... You could just remove it (almost last line of the command). Also your last sentence with "too much" could be somehow offensive... But it is not a problem for me (just mentioning in case you are not a native English speaker -me neither-)