# Hiding items in student's handout using beamer duplicate slides

Tags: beamer, handout

Motivation: giving lectures using `beamer`, I would like to hide answers from the students' handout. On one slide, I want to ask a question, show the answer after a `\pause`, ask a second question after a `\pause`, then show the answer, etc. I applied three solutions found on StackExchange (`\hideit`, `\only<beamer>`, and `\mode<beamer>`).

As the MWE below will show, the PDF when compiled with `beamer` contains more slides that it should (slides 6 and 10). Indeed, those two slides display all the information and do not make use of the `\pause`.  When using `handout`, everything is as I want it. I would like the slides under *Atmospheric pressure* to behave like under *Standard Climate Statistics*. I am not sure where the code goes awry in the second `\frame`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},t,serif,mathserif,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

%%% To create a handout version of the presentation 
%\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},handout,serif,mathserif,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Goettingen}
    \usecolortheme{seagull}
}

%To hite text in handout from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266116/trying-to-hide-blocks-of-text-in-beamer
\newcommand\hideit[1]{%
  \only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
  \invisible<0| handout:1>{#1}}
    
\begin{document}

\section{Climate statistics}
%%----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[c]{Standard climate statistics}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcolor{ForestGreen}{Arithmetic mean} (or average)
    
    \pause
    \item Sum of the values, x$_i$, divided by the number of observations, N
\end{itemize}

\begin{align}
    \hideit{\bar{x_i} = \dfrac{\sum x_i}{N}}
\end{align}

%\begin{align}
%   \only<beamer>{\bar{x_i} = \dfrac{\sum x_i}{N}}
%\end{align}

%\mode<beamer>{%
%\begin{align}
%   \bar{x_i} = \dfrac{\sum x_i}{N}
%\end{align}
%}

\pause
\begin{itemize}
    \item A measure of variability such as \textcolor{ForestGreen}{standard deviation}, S$_n$
\end{itemize}

\pause
\begin{align}
    \hideit{S_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x_i})^2}}
\end{align}

%\begin{align}
%   \only<beamer>{S_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x_i})^2}}
%\end{align}

%\mode<beamer>{%
%\begin{align*}
%   S_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x_i})^2}
%\end{align*}
%}
\end{frame}

%%----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[c]{Atmospheric pressure}

\begin{itemize}
    \item How can we calculate the dry air density, $\rho_{air}$?
\end{itemize}

\pause
\begin{align}
    \hideit{\rho_{air} =\pause \dfrac{m_{air}}{V_{air}}}
\end{align}

%\begin{align}
%   \only<beamer>{\rho_{air} =\pause \dfrac{m_{air}}{V_{air}}}
%\end{align}

%\mode<beamer>{%
%\begin{align}
%       \rho_{air} =\pause \dfrac{m_{air}}{V_{air}}
%\end{align}
%}  

\pause
\begin{itemize}
    \item How can we calculate the mass of a given dry air parcel, $m_{air}$?
\end{itemize}

\pause
\begin{align}
    \hideit{m_{air} =\pause n_{air} MM_{air}}
\end{align}

%\begin{align}
%   \only<beamer>{m_{air} =\pause n_{air} MM_{air}}
%\end{align}

%\mode<beamer>{%
%\begin{align}
%   m_{air} =\pause n_{air} MM_{air}
%\end{align}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine pointed out that there are extra `\pause` inside the equations. Removing them did the trick.