# How to locally deactivate \phantom

Tags: phantom

I need to use \phantom for an argument and to deactivate it just sometimes to show only the numbers of enumerates. I spend a lot of time and I tried many things but I can't achieve it. Here is a minimal example (for xelatex) which I know it can't work but it show the quite simple idea :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{french}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\fantome}[1]
    {
    \begin{phantom}
    #1
    \end{phantom}
    }

\let\itemold\item
\renewcommand{\item}{
    \end{phantom}
    \itemold
    \begin{phantom}
    }


Ici les questions.\\
\fantome{Ici les réponses.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Réponse 1.
\item Réponse 2.
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I would like to have:

[image]

I tried to be concise but I can explain more if needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there a reason for not writing `\newcommand{\fantome}[1]{\phantom{#1}}`

Comment: That won't work, you can't use \phantom as environment. Check the lualatex versions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555595/multilines-multipages-phantom-analog-macro

Comment: I tried \newcommand{\fantome}[1]{\phantom{#1}} and other things but I am not very good in tex/latex. I understand \phantom can't be used as environment, but so how can I do ? No way to achieve my purpose (which appear quite simple I think, it's just a on/off phantom command).