# How to get the current background color in xcolor?

Tags: color

I read the [xcolor documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) and I understood that `.` is a placeholder for the current text color. How can I get the current **background** color?

ps: The final purpose of this is to temporarily hide a text; for example if `..` is a placeholder for the current background color, I could use `\colorlet{tmp}{.}\color{..}#1\color{tmp}`.

Comment: There isn't a 'current background' in TeX terms: are you perhaps using `beamer`?

Comment: No I am not using `beamer.` I just need to sometimes hide parts of a document. I can't use `\phantom` because it is incompatible with lists (itemize & enumerate).

Comment: by default there is no background color at all. You can add one with \pagecolor{somecolor} (and then you would know the color). Beside this: setting the color of text doesn't really hide it, it can still be copy&pasted from the file.

Comment: Plus there could be colour boxes or stuff overlaying stuff: really, 'this won't work'

Comment: @ JosephWright "setting the color of text doesn't really hide it, it can still be copy&pasted from the file." I know that but I don't have better idea. As I said, `phantom` simply don't work at all with `itemize`: a code as simple as `\phantom{\begin{itemize}\item test\end{itemize}}` make an error (I am beginning to think that LaTeX is mainly a tricks & hacks language ;) ).If you have another idea for a better hiding, feel free to share it, I will be happy to use it. Thanks

Comment: I already told you in your other question: the best way to hide text completly is to use lualatex and the lua-ul package. If you don't care about copy&paste then you can also use the transparent package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555681/2388.

Comment: I can't use LuaLatex (around 2 times slower for me so it's a no go because I need to compile very often + the tex files are shared, so it's complicated to change everybody config). I yet tried the transparent package but it seems to don't work at all on my config (the last version of this package is from 2007, maybe it is no more compatible with recent Miktex ?). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should correctly ping people if you want them to see your comments. The newest version of transparent is from 2019: `[2019/11/29 v1.4 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)]%`, and it is also in a current miktex. If you have an outdated transparent version if can clash with tikz and so loose transparency.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for you explanation, I am trying to learn: I definitively made a mistake about the version. But now I have the messages `Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode` and `Undefined control sequence. \transparent`: not sure if transparent package is compatible with XeLaTeX...

Comment: no transparent doesn't work with xelatex, xelatex doesn't have the needed color stacks. But if you are using already an unicode engine, why it is so difficult for you to switch to lualatex?