# Linux Biolinum Keyboard missing euro currency symbol

Tags: symbols, libertine, biolinum

Some keyboards provide a key with the € currency symbol (U+20AC), but the Linux Biolinum Keyboard font is missing it, though:

- it does provide some currency symbols,
- Linux Libertine does provide this symbol,

as shown by the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
€ \LKey{uni00A5} \LKey{uni0024} \LKey{uni00A3} \fbox{\LKey{uni20AC}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way  (even a poor man's one) to get the € in Linux Biolinum Keyboard?

### Edit

BTW, the same deficiency is affecting the [Libertinus fonts fork](https://github.com/alerque/libertinus/) of Linux Libertine.

Comment: Not satisfactory, but the only thing I can think of is to create a small image in the style of the other currency symbols, and use that.

Comment: A quick mockup: https://i.ibb.co/c62n6Lm/euro.png

Comment: @Ingmar Hey, not that bad! :) I'll adopt this workaround if nothing less dirty comes up ;)

Answer (score 9):

Bad hack: use the keyboard centered dot, cover the dot with a white larger centered dot and print the Euro symbol above it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\newcommand{\LKeyEuro}{{%
  \ooalign{%
    \LKey{uni00B7}\cr % the keyboard centered dot
    \hidewidth % a centered dot in white to mask off
      \sffamily
      \kern-0.06em
      \raisebox{-0.03ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{\color{white}\char"B7}}%
    \hidewidth\cr
    \hidewidth % the Euro sign
      \sffamily
      \kern-0.075em
      \raisebox{0.125ex}{\scalebox{0.75}{€}}%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
}}

\begin{document}

\LKeyEuro\ \LKey{uni00A5} \LKey{uni0024} \LKey{uni00A3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This bad hack works nicely! Except if the background color of the page isn't white :) And https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559826/18401 leaves little hope...

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I’m wondering why the authors of the font didn’t think to add a blank key shape.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Another strategy could be to produce with `standalone` a picture of one key, edit the PDF to remove the character inside and use it as above.

Answer (score 4):

Linux Biolinum Keyboard is licensed under the GPL, so you can modify the font to add the Euro glyph using an application such as [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/). You should be able to copy an existing character to create the key-shaped border. If another variant of Linux Biolinum includes a Euro glyph, you can combine the existing glyph with the border. The FontForge editor works like other vector graphics applications, with nodes and handles for adjusting the shapes. [Design with FontForge](https://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Using_the_Fontforge_Drawing_Tools.html) offers helpful instructions.

Comment: Well, beyond my scope I'm afraid. I opened [a feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/340/), with little hope since the project seems to be not very active. I also opened [a feature request](https://github.com/alerque/libertinus/issues/504) on the Libertinus fonts fork.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new package on ctan: circledtext. Something to play with and postpone the boring things. See yourself:

```
\documentclass[24pt, parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{circledtext, xcolor}
\circledtextset{boxtype=OO, boxlinewidth=0.5pt, charf=\sffamily, charshrink=0.5,
  yscale=1.5, width=2em, resize=real}
\newcommand{\clb}[1]{\circledtext*{#1}}
\newcommand{\cls}[1]{\circledtext{#1}}
\begin{document}


\cls{T} \cls{y} \cls{p} \cls{e}\,\clb{:} \cls{€} 

\clb{T} \clb{y} \clb{p} \clb{e}\,\cls{:} \clb{€} 

Or even:

\circledtextset{boxtype=O, boxlinewidth=0.5pt, charf=\sffamily\bfseries, charshrink=0.5,
  yscale=1.5, width=2em, boxfill=red!50, charcolor=white, resize=real}

\circledtext{€}

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image: Circledtext picture]