# Hide matters in article

Tags: macros, spacing, page-breaking, text-decorations

I want to hide something in a article. Hidden contents may be large enough to span muli-line multi-paragrph, and even muli-page.

I find a solution by **mathspasha** from [How to replace a large block of text by an empty block of the same size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43069/how-to-replace-a-large-block-of-text-by-an-empty-block-of-the-same-size) as the following code showes. It's simple and I like the idea(global switch and put hidden content to far left).

It works all fine except that text post `\show` begins a new paragraph. I wonder if something can be done to improve this solution to achieve a in-line phantom, I mean when hidden part finished, no new paragraph is created. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

**CODE:**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \long\def\hide#1\show{%
        \leavevmode\par
       \hspace*{-10000pt}\vbox\bgroup#1\egroup
       \par
    }
    \def\show{}
    \begin{document}
    Mark A
    \hide
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \show
    Mark B

And I hope the folowing two paragraphs have the same shape whet typeset.

|some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text|

|some text \hide some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some \show text some text|

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the code starts and ends with `\par`, so you have a new paragraph. However, also changing this will never work across pages.

Comment: I tried removing `\par`. Then the code failed to work. So, how to improve it to phantom matters in-line and support multi-lines and multi-pages?

Comment: A luatex solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555697/82917

Comment: Thanks. Any other way other than lua ,especially works on the current code?

Comment: There is also the [censor package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/censor/censor.pdf) and the [comment package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf) and some other packages in the category [conditional compilation](https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp).

Comment: @Marijn Seems that macros(\censer, \blackout)  of package  censor do not surport line-break(`\\\`, or `\linebreak`) in hidden text. Any method to solve it?

Comment: @lyl https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break is related (uses the `ulem` package instead of `censor`). Or as an alternaitve solution you can choose to not use `\newline` at all and use `\par` (or empty lines) instead.

Comment: use \par (or empty lines) will cause unexpected parindent.

Comment: @lyl `\par\noindent` creates a new paragraph without indentation.

Comment: @Marjin Vertical spacing would be different between `\newline` and `\par\noindent`. And seems that this can not work with `uline` from package `ulem`. Any better way for this?